# Smooth scroll to id except when user is already at that location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running the following script when a user clicks on a button, to scroll to a specific div on the page, along with a few other unrelated functions.

The problem is that the button itself is supposed to always remains in view, and thus can be spam-clicked to cause the page to 'lag' while it's busy moving over and over to the same location. I would like to counter this behavior by only executing the scroll when the page is not already at that specific location.

Unfortunately I have no real experience working with JavaScript/jQuery and have not been able to find an example of something like this being used.

Here's my sample code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="navButton">Button</div>

<div id="listContent">Content that must be visible after button click goes here</div>
```

**Script**

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("navButton").onclick = function(){
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#listContent").offset().top -165}, 400);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide JSFiddle for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this Example could help you... Change the hash first then listen to the hashchange Event. When you reload the page it will scroll down to your anchor.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   // check for hash when page has loaded
   if (getHash() != null) {
     checkForScrolling();
   }
 });
 // check for hash when hash has changed
 window.onhashchange = function() {
   checkForScrolling();
 };
 // return hash if so or null if hash is empty
 function getHash() {
     var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
     if (hash != '') {
       return hash;
     } else {
       return null;
     }
   }
   // this function handles your scrolling

 function checkForScrolling() {
   // first get your element by attribute selector
   var elem = $('[data-anchor="' + getHash() + '"]');
   // cheeck if element exists
   if (elem.length > 0) {
     $('html, body').stop().animate({
       scrollTop: elem.offset().top
     }, 300);
   }
 }
```

```css
 body {
   font-family: Helvetica
 }
 section {
   position: relative;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   padding: 20px;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: #eee;
 }
 section a {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1 data-anchor="start">Smooth Scrolling</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#1">Scroll to Anchor 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#2">Scroll to Anchor 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#3">Scroll to Anchor 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <section>
    <h2 data-anchor="1">First Anchor</h2>
    <a href="#start">Back to top</a>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2 data-anchor="2">Second Anchor</h2>
    <a href="#start">Back to top</a>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2 data-anchor="3">Third Anchor</h2>
    <a href="#start">Back to top</a>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if worked

```
<div id="navButton" onclick="moveElement('listContent');">Button</div>
<div id="listContent">Content that must be visible after button click goes here</div>
```

You will need jquery included for this script code

```
function moveElement(divId) {
    $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#"+divId).offset().top
     }, 2000);
}
```

And if you see it not working then try by adding below css. It will make gap between button and your div.

```
    #navButton {
        height: 300px;
        border:1px solid green;
    }
    #listContent {
        height: 900px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
```